# Azure Notification Hub tag expressions not working for multiple tags

Tags: azure, tags, azure-notificationhub

I'm testing a free tier notification hub on Azure and the tags functionality doesn't seem to be working as intended. I'm pretty sure it's working as there might be a ton of companies using it, but I don't know whats wrong with my tests.

I have the app installed on two android devices, all registered correctly with the hub.
One has one tag, the other has 3 tags.

[image]

When I go to the test page of the notification hub and send one notification without tags, both devices receive them.
If I add the `RECEIVER` tag, only the first device receives even if the second one also has this tag.
If I use a tag expression (as per their documentation) like `RECEIVER && Curitiba && PR`, the second device does not receive it either. All I get is this response:

[image]

I'm sure the service allow devices to have more than one tag and that the tag expressions are allowed on the free tier(haven't seen any restriction about it anywhere)

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I was adding(via code) multiple tags all at once like "RECEIVER,Curitiba,PR" and that might have confused the notification back-end. I removed the tags and added them one by one and that worked out just fine.

I think they could specify that in the documentation and also throw an exception if they are added with commas.

Comment: Interesting, this sounds like a bug. Were you using an SDK or the REST endpoints directly?

Comment: Using the .NET SDK.
I've opened a issue on the SDK github page about it (https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet/issues/193)